# specifiy different gradle properties file for Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, gradle, build

I am trying to add continuos integration for our project using Jenkins. Its a gradle project and we set some environment variables in the properties files. We have the project in SVN. I am able to retreive the project from SVN using subversion plugin for jenkins. But each developer has differnt environment variables added. How do I add one specific to jenkins?

Is there anyway to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file in your Jenkins machine? You can stick properties there to apply to your build.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I created the properties file in the user.home directory of jenkins. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Copying my comment from above for anyone looking to answer this in the future:*

You could put CI-specific properties in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` for the Jenkins user.